# AZCopy Copy results in 404 blob does not exist

Tags: command-line, azcopy

When running AZCopy command copy to get 2 pictures from a blob container/ folder, it results in a 404 blog not found.  Error does not occur if I specify the filename (it downloads the folder structure with the file in it).

Tested 3 different versions of it the code but can not get a recursive version to work.

Example of not working
azcopy copy "https://bloburl.blob.core.windows.net/Container/Folder/*?SASKey" "C:\Users\MyFolder\Pictures"

azcopy copy "https://bloburl.blob.core.windows.net/Container/Folder?SASKey" "C:\Users\MyFolder\Pictures"

Example of working

azcopy copy "https://bloburl.blob.core.windows.net/Container/Folder/UNSC_Infinity.jpg?SASKey" "C:\Users\MyFolder\Pictures"

My goal is to download all files in the blob container/folder and not the structure itself.

SAS URI: https://s00aops01stg01blkbsa.blob.core.windows.net/5740-christianmimms?st=2019-06-03T17%3A09%3A34Z&se=2020-06-04T17%3A09%3A00Z&sp=rwl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=3HyCaMQ1JCkb4Yof%2BOWExx8amHtPTmZHpEZbZPX8Iqs%3D

SAS URI w/Folder:  https://s00aops01stg01blkbsa.blob.core.windows.net/5740-christianmimms/images/*?st=2019-06-03T17%3A09%3A34Z&se=2020-06-04T17%3A09%3A00Z&sp=rwl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=3HyCaMQ1JCkb4Yof%2BOWExx8amHtPTmZHpEZbZPX8Iqs%3D

Comment: Just to confirm, does your SAS have permission to **list** blobs?

Comment: I can't garuntee it as I can't seem to find my privileges.  At one point in the storage explorer UI it showed me as a user with read, write and delete privileges.

Comment: What's the value of "sp" parameter in your SAS? It's supposed to contain "l" which stands for **List**.

Comment: SP values sp=rwdl

Comment: Hmm... It's weird, have you verified if the SAS is still working by trying to download a blob in browser with SAS in the end of URL?

Comment: I will try first thing tomrrow, but i'm sure the blob is still working as we use it for other projects.  I have simply created a single folder with my name so I don't impact the others.

Comment: I confirmed all other folders are working. I did notice that if I tell the Storage Explorer UI to download 2 files at once it fails.  I had my team spin up a new storage container I can share, where AZCopy still fails:

SAS URI added to original post